# fgets giving me a segfault when passing only spaces

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am trying to make a shell and one of the conditions i am looking out for is when the user enters a bunch of spaces. However, I get a segfault from fgets when I input any number of spaces in the terminal. It can be one space, or it can be a whole bunch of them followed by a random character. I keep getting a segfault.

*Development:*
I noticed that I don't get a segfault when I remove my tokenize function. Why would this be the case?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* Initialize variables and methods */

int status;
int i;
int one_nonspace = -1;
int on = 1;
char input[101];
char temp[101];
char* tokenized;
char operators[3] = {'>', '<', '|'};
char** tokens;



void getInput(char *prmpt, char *buff){

    printf(">:");
    fgets(buff, 101, stdin); //segfault here when input spaces.

    /*printf("works!");*/

    if(one_nonspace != -1){
      printf("spaces");

      memcpy( temp, &buff[i], (101-i) );
      temp[100] = '\0';


    }


    if(buff[strlen(buff) -1] != '\n'){
        int over = 0;

        while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n')
            over++;

        if(over>0)
        {
            printf("Command is over 100 characters. Please try again\n");
            status = 1;
        }
    }

    else{
        buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
        status = 0;
    }



}


char** tokenize(char* a_str)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = ' ';
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
   while (*tmp)
    {
        if (' ' == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}



/* Create a parser Feb 2*/


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  while(on){

      getInput(">: ", input);
      tokenized = input;



      if(status == 0){
          /*printf("%s\n", input);*/

      }




      /*Split the line into tokens*/
      if(input[0] != ' ')
        tokens = tokenize(tokenized);

      /*if tokens[0] == 'exit', then quit.
      */

      if(strcmp(*(tokens),"exit") == 0){
        break;}


  /*2/3 Now we need to do something with the split up tokens*/
      /*printf("input after token: %s\n", input);*/
  /*Free the tokens at the end!!! Remember this!*/
      if (tokens)
      {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
      {
          printf("%s\n", *(tokens + i));
          free(*(tokens + i));
      }

      free(tokens);
      }
    }


    return 0;




}
```

Comment: No crash for me.  What platform are you on?  What's the minimum input to make it crash?  Is this your exact, actual code?

Comment: No crash here. Is this the exact crashing code? Does this code crash for you?

Comment: No it's not my entire code. I got rid of some stuff that I didn't think was neccessary. I'll re-edit my code so that it is all in there. Sorry. Update: code is all in there now!

Comment: The segfault is at `if(strcmp(*(tokens),"exit") == 0){`. A debugger can help you find things like this.

Comment: You should be checking the return value from `fgets()`.  However, that is probably not the direct cause of your crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
 /*Split the line into tokens*/
 if(input[0] != ' ')
   tokens = tokenize(tokenized);

 /*if tokens[0] == 'exit', then quit.
 */

 if(strcmp(*(tokens),"exit") == 0){
   break;}
```

When input begins with a space character, you skip the tokenize function and attempt to dereference `tokens` - a NULL pointer.

Edit: you are trying to debug with print statements and that is a valid method, but remember to flush the buffers or you won't get an accurate idea of where the problem is if the crash happens before there's any output. You can flush them explicitly with `fflush` or simply use newline characters if you're on a terminal, as they are usually line buffered.

Comment: Although I also think it would  be better if it was explicitly initialized to `NULL`, in this case, it's not absolutely necessary. Uninitialized variables with static duration start out as zero.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that you had to declare your variables as `static` for that to happen, even at global scope. Doing some reading on other questions here, I now see that that isn’t the case.